# SonarQube in jenkinsfile - stop if quality check is failed

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using [newtmitch/sonar-scanner](https://hub.docker.com/r/newtmitch/sonar-scanner/) to scan my code. I'm using it as a stage in jenkinsfile. My question is, if it is possible to stop the CI (stop the jenkins pipeline build), if the quality check is not passed.

In [this](https://medium.com/@rosaniline/setup-sonarqube-with-jenkins-declarative-pipeline-75bccdc9075f) article, they used `waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true`, to stop the pipeline if the quality gate is not passed. Can I do the same from the docker?

My docker stage look like that:

```
stage('Run sonar scanner docker'){
      sh(script:"""
            sudo docker run -v $(pwd):/usr/src --network host .../newtmitch-scanner
      """)
}
```

Plus I have sonar-project.properties file with properties in the path.

Answer (score 0):

to fail a pipeline you need your command to return an exit code of failure that is different from 0 (success). If "newtmitch-scanner" always returns a success code, but returns output, what you could do is use `grep` command with option `-q` to look for the success message